# Object undefined on click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a member function of my Utilities object on button click. The js file containing the object is loaded at the top of the `index.php` page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utilities.js"></script>
...
```

And have defined the button:

```
<button id="testAJAX" onclick="Utilties.loadSavedGames()">Load Game</button>
```

When I click, I get `Utilties is not defined` error:

```
var Utilities = {
     loadSavedGames : function () {
        console.log("Clicked"); //returns Utilties is not defined
     },...
```

But I'm curious why if I reload the page, it's able to call the anon function. This tells me that the Utilties object is clearly being loaded at page load:

```
var Utilities = {
    doThis : (function() {
        console.log("Utilities object loaded"); //runs just fine
    })(),
```

So if the object is loaded at top of `index.php` page, why would `onclick` tell me the object is undefined?

Comment: Are you sure `Utilities` is accessible in the global scope? Perhaps try `window.Utilities` instead of `var Utilities`.

Comment: Not enough information to give an answer, but does utilities.js place a reference to Utilities on window?  So window.Utilities? Seems to be a JavaScript closure issue that you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript you are setting `Utilities`, but your onclick is referencing `Utilties`. Missing an `i`.

Comment: @Growler happens to the best of them. :) I find using an IDE that highlights undeclared variables can help reduce this kind of thing. Or copy/pasting as much as possible.